# Asking a number of basic questions

Tags: discussion

I am currently studying to gain Azure Certification, and rather than just blindly going through the topics, I am compiling a collection of Azure PowerShell scripts that cover *every* aspect that is required for certification.

However, the Azure PowerShell documentation is very sparse in places. For instance I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34572032/how-to-configure-github-etc-for-azure-via-powershell) question, because I couldn't easily find that answer online.

If I continue with my plan to create a collection of scripts, it's very likely that I would need to ask quite a few "How do I do x in Azure PowerShell" type questions. I imagine the answers will generally follow the style of "You use this command with these parameters", making them pretty easy to answer for someone who has the knowledge to do so.

However, I am concerned/conscious of the basicness of the questions and whether either that or considering the 50/month limit, if I were to ask those 50 questions over the next month and whether that would be an issue.

**Edit**

My concern is the research effort aspect, to take it out of an Azure context (which not everybody will know the nuance of). Imagine that I'm looking for a way to list a directory via PowerShell, and that the `ls` command is largely undocumented online.

In that case it is difficult to make the question any more complete than: "How do I list a hidden directory in PowerShell", to which the answer is "You use this command with these parameters".

It is difficult to ask that question any differently, because it is so basic. Until I know about `ls`, there isn't much I can do to show that I've done my homework, because it is such an atomic concept.

I am trying to understand the best way to make that a *good* question.

Comment: If you ask good questions, that would be a refreshing change. If it was more than a drop in an ocean. If they are bad, you'll hopefully get downvoted, and thus automatically rate-limited and warned, probably early enough to save you from ruin.

Comment: @Deduplicator I guess that is the point of this post, is a very basic question of "how do I do x in Azure Powershell" a good question. And who knows, maybe I'll learn to ask good questions along the way!

Comment: Usually it depends mostly upon just ***how*** you ask it. If you ask it in a way that shows that you've done your homework, that you've tried something, but it's not working, that your question is as specific as can be, that you show any and all error messages, you'll likely get up-votes and decent answers.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels (I do always laugh at that name - and the Hungarian accent it comes in) I have edited the question to address that comment a little.

Comment: 50 questions per month is a _lot_. That's more that 3 questions every 2 days. If you really have that many questions about the language, you really should look up a tutorial, or search for existing questions.

Comment: @Cerbrus it is a lot, and I don't know that here would be that many (I also don't know that there wouldn't be) The problem is that these are very specific questions about relatively new technology. There simply aren't tutorials on this stuff, and very poor documentation (compare [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt652512.aspx) with [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh849800.aspx) ) SO seems as good a place as any to fill in the holes in the documentation for those who are looking to solve the same problems

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case, good questions on here are the way to go, it seems.

Comment: What documentation are you referring to specifically that is failing you? It seems Microsoft has released a free e-book for it: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2015/03/06/free-ebook-microsoft-azure-essentials-azure-automation.aspx

Comment: @Gimby If you look at the two links in my previous comment, the official documentation for the commands simply has automated placeholders, there is no information on how the parameters are used. Also if you look at the [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34572032/how-to-configure-github-etc-for-azure-via-powershell) I've asked there's nothing in that ebook that would answer that question. There is a huge amount of high level overview documentation, there's very little for those who want to get their hands dirty writing code and creating solutions.

Comment: Its an interesting question actually. MSDN is not official documentation; its official **free** documentation, and you get what you pay for sometimes. When the free documentation is lacking, I assume there is an expensive book you are supposed to be buying to get the real truth. So say hypothetically that is true, is it then the right way to ask dozens of questions to have other people, who probably do have that expensive book, provide you with all the answers? I still think yes, because SO is about questions and answers. And you've got questions to ask that can benefit others too.

Comment: @Gimby I'm an (Azure) geek, AFAIK there is no book, manual or pamphlet. No workflow or best practice that lets me know how to obtain these answers. Though I do appreciate your optimism ;) - If it was just a case of going and purchasing some documentation, I would happily do so and self answer all of the questions I'll come up against. I believe it is a result of the speed at which features are released on Azure (my experience of AWS is similar) The Azure team release a feature + API, the Azure Powershell team create cmdlets and at some point way off in the future flesh out the automated docs

Comment: Sounds like there's an opportunity for Azure documentation in that new SE documentation beta thingy?

Comment: @PeterTirrell I'd forgotten all about the SE Documentation thingy (is that the official name now?!) It would actually be a really good solution for a lot of that documentation. - Maybe I'll even go and get signed up for - we can't just go and browse it yet can we?

Answer (score 20):

I like to answer questions in a related tag ([aws-powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-powershell)) and see questions like you're describing often.

Simple questions aren't inherently bad! It is okay that you don't know all of the terminology and/or concepts of the technology you're working on. However, not having this knowledge will put more responsibility on you as the asker to clearly explain what you're trying to do. Generally, from a place of little understanding I like to see:

- **A clear problem statement:** This is the most important takeaway and separates good-simple questions from bad-simple questions. What *exactly* are you trying to do, in your own words?
- **Appropriate tagging:** This topic doesn't have a large following on Stack Overflow, so bad tagging could cause the question to be missed by other users. For example, the question you linked tags [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell) and [azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure), but not the tag for the module itself -- [azure-powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-powershell). Experts in the azure powershell module are most likely to review that tag specifically, so don't leave it out. Spend some time in the tags tab to discover tags related to Azure.  A good place to start is to search for `[azure-*]`.
- **Your research:** Asking a question here shouldn't be the first step to solving your problem. Look for documentation first.  If you can't find any, that doesn't mean it doesn't exist -- let us know in your question body. A user may take additional time to link to appropriate documentation if you need help finding it.
- **Your progress:** What have you done so far? If you've written any code yet (even pseudocode -- this helps to express what you're trying to do!) share it.  If it isn't working, include any relevant exceptions or output that would help to diagnose the problem.

Very helpful answers to questions like this will take time to explain what their completed code example is doing, and often link to related documentation. If someone posts code as an answer with inadequate elaboration, there is no harm in replying with a comment to ask for further details or links to documentation, or even continuing a longer discussion in chat if it is warranted.

Comment: This is a good answer, One of my primary thoughts for asking the questions here - as well as to find the answer - is to have an answer at the end of an internet search for the next someone who is frustrated by lacking documentation. So wording the questions in a way that asks directly as well as simplifying the concepts a little might be useful.